# Trying to understand the vtable content

Tags: c++, vtable

I have this example code:

https://godbolt.org/z/reM8PY8r9

```cpp
struct Base {
    Base() {}
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct Derived: public Base {
    Derived(): Base() { }

    void foo() {
        return;
    }
};

Base* todolist[2] = { new Derived()};

void realtime() {
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
        todolist[i]->foo();
}
```

Which produces this AVR assembly:

```
__tmp_reg__ = 0
Derived::foo():
  ret
realtime():
  lds r26,todolist
  lds r27,todolist+1
  ld r30,X+
  ld r31,X
  sbiw r26,1
  ld __tmp_reg__,Z+
  ld r31,Z
  mov r30,__tmp_reg__
  ldi r24,hi8(gs(Derived::foo()))
  cpi r30,lo8(gs(Derived::foo()))
  cpc r31,r24
  brne .L9
.L4:
  lds r26,todolist+2
  lds r27,todolist+2+1
  ld r30,X+
  ld r31,X
  sbiw r26,1
  ld __tmp_reg__,Z+
  ld r31,Z
  mov r30,__tmp_reg__
  ldi r24,hi8(gs(Derived::foo()))
  cpi r30,lo8(gs(Derived::foo()))
  cpc r31,r24
  brne .L10
  ret
.L9:
  movw r24,r26
  icall
  rjmp .L4
.L10:
  movw r24,r26
  ijmp
_GLOBAL__sub_I_todolist:
  ldi r24,lo8(2)
  ldi r25,0
  rcall operator new(unsigned int)
  movw r30,r24
  ldi r24,lo8(vtable for Derived+4)
  ldi r25,hi8(vtable for Derived+4)
  std Z+1,r25
  st Z,r24
  sts todolist+1,r31
  sts todolist,r30
  ret
vtable for Derived:
  .word 0
  .word 0
  .word gs(Derived::foo())
todolist:
  .zero 4
```

What I'm trying to understand is the vtable:

```
vtable for Derived:
  .word 0
  .word 0
  .word gs(Derived::foo())
```

Why it's not just the foo pointer for example like this?

```
vtable for Derived:
  .word gs(Derived::foo())
```

That's what I would assume it to be from literature, but I'm not sure if literature is glancing over some specific detail. Each class has own vtable with pointer to their own methods or their base classes depending how they inherit/implement/override them. Then the vptr is in each instance of the classes point to their corresponding vtable. I would expect the vtable have just the pointer to that one and only method the classes, What are the zeros before it, what is exact structure of the vtable?

Comment: The vtable is an implementation detail, and not part of the C++ standard.  There are no C++ mechanisms to access it.  It doesn't even have to exist (because it is an implementation detail, and the equivalent may be done differently).  Any vtable answer will be specific to a particular compiler on a given platform.

Comment: And one possible answer is that the extra space is used to find (in an implementation-specific manner) information related to run-time type information.

Comment: Other common things in vtables is data to support RTTI and virtual inheritance. Alternatively that implementation may reserve slots for virtual destructors and the like even if they don’t exist. As it’s an implementation detail you’d have to look up that compilers source or specifications

Comment: @Eljay thank you, for clarification. Would you know how GCC implemnted vtables specifically for the AVR platform?

Comment: @SoronelHaetir the vtable is the same with `-fno-rtti` flag

Comment: The first result for Google for gcc vtable  layout gives https://ww2.ii.uj.edu.pl/~kapela/pn/cpp_vtable.html which looks pretty relevant. So it looks like those first 2 numbers are topoffset and typeinfo

Comment: @MikeVine I was googling it for 2 days, but I was always googling it wrong, for some reason was assuming this is fully specified by standard and never googled it with a mindset of this being toolchain specific. Now when thinking it's obvious, but before it didn't crossed my mind. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm glad we were able to provide you enough information to get you pointed in the right direction.  I don't know about GCC's vtable implementation on AVR, but it appears you've gotten some links to the information you wanted.

Comment: Yes I will read futher into it and then collate the answer. Looks like the linked document has minor mistakes in the diagram (referencing fields a and b as x and y), but overall it's pretty good.